# Does this discrete probability distribution have a name? (Related to Hypergeometric distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, sampling-theory

Suppose there are $N$ objects, of which $K$ are of type 1 and $N-K$ of type 2. Objects of type 1 are indistinguishable and objects of type 2 are indistinguishable. One is interested in the probability of getting $k$ objects of type 1 in $n$ draws from $N$, with replacement. This probability then is given by

$$\frac{\frac{K^{k}}{k!} \frac{(N-K)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{\frac{N^{n}}{n!}}$$

Does this probability distribution have a name? It looks like it's related to hypergeometric distribution with the difference being that here we are drawing with replacement...

Edit. Taking another look at it, one can write the above as

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{K^{k}}{N^{k}}\frac{(N-K)^{n-k}}{N^{n-k}}$$ which is the binomial distribution with parameter $p = \frac{K}{N}$, i.e. the probability of "success" when you perform $n=1$ draws, right?

Comment: this is a binomial distribution

Comment: thanks!  @Tortar

Comment: @Tortar : If your comments answered the question, you should post an answer. In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not require reading comments for essential information.  On the other hand, if you think the answer is too trivial or this question is too trivial for an answer, you should vote to close this question.

Comment: For your edit, yes you're right @Sasha1001 :-)

Comment: @Peter O. yes but with the edit I think the OP answered the question so now we could agree that the post is self-contained

Comment: @Tortar: Yes, but every answered question should also have an answer (post).